# Using SageMaker pipe mode with an s3 directory of tfrecords

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-datasets

My call to `sagemaker.tensorflow.TensorFlow.fit()` hangs indefinitely with no error message when I use `Pipe` instead of `File` as the `input_mode`. I correspondingly replace the TensorFlow `Dataset` with `Pipemodedataset`. The training in `File` mode completes successfully.

My data consists of two s3 buckets with multiple tfrecord files in each. Despite having looked extensively through the documentation, I am not confident about how to use the `Pipemodedataset` in this case - specifically, how to set the `channel`.

Here is my Sagemaker notebook setup:

```
hyperparameters = {
    "batch-size": 1,
    "pipe_mode": 1,
}

estimator_config = {
    "entry_point": "tensorflow_train.py",
    "source_dir": "source",
    "framework_version": "2.3",
    "py_version": "py37",
    "instance_type": "ml.p3.2xlarge",
    "instance_count": 1,
    "role": sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    "hyperparameters": hyperparameters,
    "output_path": f"s3://{bucket_name}",
    "input_mode": "Pipe",
}

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(**estimator_config)

s3_data_channels = {
    "training": f"s3://{bucket_name}/data/training",
    "validation": f"s3://{bucket_name}/data/validation",
}

tf_estimator.fit(s3_data_channels)
```

If I were to run `aws s3 ls` on the `s3_data_channels`, I'd get a list of tfrecord files.

Here is the way I set up the dataset (see the if / else statement depending on whether `pipe_mode` is selected:

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == "__main__":

    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...
    arg_parser.add_argument("--pipe_mode", type=int, default=0)

    arg_parser.add_argument("--train_dir", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING"))
    arg_parser.add_argument(
        "--validation_dir", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_VALIDATION")
    )
    arg_parser.add_argument("--model_dir", type=str)
    args, _ = arg_parser.parse_known_args()

    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

    if args.pipe_mode == 1:
        from sagemaker_tensorflow import PipeModeDataset
        train_ds = PipeModeDataset(channel="training", record_format='TFRecord')
        val_ds = PipeModeDataset(channel="validation", record_format='TFRecord')

    else:
        train_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(args.train_dir + '/*tfrecord')
        val_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(args.validation_dir + '/*tfrecord')
        train_ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=train_files, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
        val_ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=val_files, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)

    train_ds = (
        train_ds.map(tfrecord_parser, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .batch(args.batch_size)
        .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )

    val_ds = (
        val_ds.map(tfrecord_parser, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
        .batch(args.batch_size)
        .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )
    ...
```

Comment: The Notebook output is: 
```2021-11-04 01:17:08 Starting - Starting the training job...
2021-11-04 01:17:11 Starting - Launching requested ML instances......
2021-11-04 01:18:33 Starting - Preparing the instances for training.........
2021-11-04 01:19:54 Downloading - Downloading input data...
2021-11-04 01:20:10 Training - Downloading the training image...............
2021-11-04 01:23:02 Training - Training image download completed. Training in progress..```
It prints the environment variables, then hangs at
```hook.py:425] Monitoring the collections: sm_metrics, metrics, losses```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, model.fit() got stuck indefinitely when using pipe mode. After some research and trying a many changes it got solved by defining **steps_per_epoch** when fitting the model.

I guess when using file mode it already knows how many steps per epoch there will be, but with pipe mode you have to specify it manually

Comment: works for me too! how do you calculate this value? in other way then to run locally?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already two years. But this issue never being fix in Sagemaker or Keras.
Root cause of it is [keras.engine.data_adapter.DataHandler.enumerate_epochs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3bd7104c22651d2a1e5b85d189c0d7e33475fc02/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1094) and the way that ***PipeModeDataset*** work.

When [should_recreate_iterator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3bd7104c22651d2a1e5b85d189c0d7e33475fc02/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1094) is true, it will call iter(dataset) twice in the [enumerate_epochs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3bd7104c22651d2a1e5b85d189c0d7e33475fc02/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1094), first *iterator* being discards right away.
And because the implementation of ***PipeModeDataset***, each time iterator being created it will increase the index to the next PIPE, in this case it will using PIPE ***training_1*** for the first epoch. But since PIPE ***training_0*** is not consumed, the background fetching processes won't write to  ***training_1***. So we will find the training hang.

User can easy produce it with ***PipeModeDataset*** also. Simply call

```
from sagemaker_tensorflow import PipeModeDataset
train_ds = PipeModeDataset(channel="training", record_format='TFRecord')
iter(ds)
next(iter(ds)) # it will wait forever
```

Here is monkey patch:

```
from tensorflow.python.distribute.input_lib import (
    DistributedDataset,
)
def enumerate_epochs(self):
    """Yields `(epoch, tf.data.Iterator)`."""
    with self._truncate_execution_to_epoch():
        if not self._adapter.should_recreate_iterator():
            data_iterator = iter(self._dataset)
        for epoch in range(self._initial_epoch, self._epochs):
            if self._insufficient_data:  # Set by `catch_stop_iteration`.
                break
            if self._adapter.should_recreate_iterator():
                data_iterator = iter(self._dataset)
                if not isinstance(self._dataset, DistributedDataset):
                    steps = self._infer_steps(
                        self._steps_per_epoch, self._dataset
                    )
                    if steps is not None:
                        self._inferred_steps = steps
            yield epoch, data_iterator
            self._adapter.on_epoch_end()
import keras
keras.engine.data_adapter.DataHandler.enumerate_epochs = enumerate_epochs
```